# Any solution for response.redirect in a user control

Tags: asp.net

I am using the Response.Redirect method in a User Control to allow visitors
to click an ImageButton to take them to another page. However, when I click
the ImageButton I recieve the following error:

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Looking at the error I don't think the issue is with the Response.Redirect command itself. Can you post some sample code?

Comment: What you're seeing is a NullReferenceException, a very common exception in development and impossible to diagnose without seeing some code, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Response.Redirect` works fine from within a user control.

(I think you'll need to post some code so that we can diagnose the problem properly.)